# Typescript: Determining whether a string is in a string union type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say I have a `type` defined like so: `type CheeseType = 'Cheddar' | 'Pepperjack' | 'Gouda'`.

Given a `string`, how can I determine whether that `string` value is in the `CheeseType` list?

I'm imagining something like `if (myString is CheeseType)` or `if (myString in CheeseType)`, but these don't seem to work.

Comment: I think you can't mix up typescript and javascript like that. `if` statement is related to the runtime and typescript runs before compiling

Comment: Maybe `type CheeseType` should be an `enum CheeseType` then? If it was an enum, I could get an array of the string values of `CheeseType` and see if `myString` is contained in the array, right?

Comment: If you want to use an array you could do something like [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBMAWBTRFEBUCeAHFMC8MA2gOQDCSAJhQIYBOxANDMQAqJY60BW1wA1o2YBxEAFcaxALoxqEOOGgBuAFBRsiGOWSpMOfDDU4QAMzhIU6dREJhRAWwBGiWpJWhIsAJYQtF3RoIACgAPAC4YaFpPMABzAEpw4JhvTXMddXwAPhhAhG1LHDlZGAAlRGoKcAAbDABBWlpqDAAeSOiYzLiAOmiKRGCAeWMQuJhMggAGFWUgA).  You need to pick a runtime representation of the values to check though.  Once you decide on that someone can suggest how to get the compiler to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `type CheeseType = 'Cheddar' | 'Pepperjack' | 'Gouda'` has absolutely no representation in JavaScript and is not emulated in any way. You can figure it out by copy/pasting it in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play.

So you won't be able to check the type at runtime. The only purpose of `type` is to prevent your code from compiling in case of type misuse, so you don't have to run the code to notice obvious mistakes.

You can use `enum` which has a representation in JavaScript (an object) and will allow you to make runtime type checking.